# Autowire a collection with different sources

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

I have an `@Autowired` set of the `Foo` interface and a bean that returns a set of the same class and it works perfectly. Now I have added a new component that returns an object with that implements the same interface. I naively expected the autowired to pull from both sources and combine them. But what happened is that it is creating a set with only the component.

Bar class that has the autowired.

```
public class Bar(){
    public void do(){
        foos.apply();
    }

    @Autowired
    private Collection<Foo> foos;
}
```

Config class that returns a set of `Foo`

```
@Configuration
public class Config(){

    @Bean
    public Set<Foo> getFoos(){
        Set.of(
           FooImpl1("a"),
           FooImpl1("b")
        )
    }
    }

    @Autowired
    private Collection<Foo> foos;
}
```

The above works, but when I add the following

```
@Component
public class FooImpl2 implements Foo(){
    public void apply(){
        foos.apply();
    }
}
```

The `foos` property only has 1 element and is of type `FooImpl2`.

It's there a way to make Spring understand that I want both sources of `Foo`s with `@Autowired` or do I need to change the design of the code?

Comment: What happens if you replace `getFoos()` with two separate methods that each return a single `Foo`?

Comment: Your expectations are off. When injecting a `Collection<Foo>` Spring will inject a collection with all instances of beans of type `Foo`. For which you only have 1 bean, the other method generates a bean of type `Set<Foo>` and thus not compatible. If you want all beans just make them all beans instaef of a single bean and a collection of beans.